# Can I update tesseract module for improving OCR capability of Blue Prism?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, blueprism

Blue Prism can not OCR handwriting out-of-box. I don't know if I can update built-in tesseract module (Blue Prism OCR engine) to improve its OCR capability?

Comment: Or, there are some other methods to improve the OCR capability of Blue Prism?

Comment: You should be able to install a newer version of `tesseract.exe` and `tessdata` folder into your `<Blue Prism Install Folder>/Tesseract` path. IIRC, this isn't officially supported.

Comment: Doesn't BluePrism already come with Tesseract installed?

in 6.1 release notes there is information: Version 6 is installed with Tesseract OCR V3.05.01